# I accidentally put a space in my path then moved lots of files - where are they?

Tags: bash, mv

I used the following code to move a lot of files:

```
sourceDIR=/Volumes/MCOOPER/data
destDIR=/Volumes/MCOOPER2 /data
for i in {1..6000}
do
mv $sourceDIR/run$i.mat $destDIR/
done
```

Now all my files are gone. Is there any way to retrieve them? Many thanks.

Comment: Since `destDIR` is undefined, it seems unlikely that _this script_ would do anything at all.  (Unless it is different from what you show us.)

Comment: As an aside, you could have probably run this simpler command instead: `mv /Volumes/MCOOPER/data/run{1..6000}.mat /Volumes/MCOOPER2/data`. The caveat possibly being a too long command-list, but I don't think that should be a problem on modern systems.

Comment: @Dolda2000 yes I received the argument-list too long error when I tried to do it in a one-liner.

Comment: @mr.cooper: That's a bit strange, because I didn't. Oh well.

Comment: @devnull Unfortunately the script seemed to do something because all of those files are gone now. However there is one difference between what I posted and the actual script - I left out a forward slash in my original post which has now been corrected

Comment: @mr.cooper: Did you run this script as root?

Comment: @Dolda2000 No I did not

Answer (score 0):

Note that your definition of `destDIR` does not set its value at all; it merely tries to run the program `/data` with that variable set. Since `/data` does not name a program, nothing meaningful happens.

Seeing, then, as how `$destDIR` is undefined, your `mv` command-line reduces to something like this:

```
mv /Volumes/MCOOPER/data/run10.mat /
```

It seems reasonable to assume, then, that your files have been moved into the root directory. Did you check there?

Also, as general advice, there are at least three things you might want to make a habit of to avoid accidents like this in the future:

- Always quote your parameter expansions unless you *explicity* want them to be word-split: `mv "$sourceDIR/run$i.mat" "$destDIR"`
- Unless you explicitly know that you want to replace files, run `mv` with the `-i` switch to avoid accidental replacement.
- When you know that you want to move things into a directory, it's helpful to put a final slash to that directory name as a safeguard against accidentally renaming the file(s) instead. That is: `destDIR=/Volumes/MCOOPER2/data/`

Additionally, you may or may not, depending on your circumstances, want to run `set -e`, to make the shell exit as soon as any command fails, instead of proceeding with subsequent commands.

Comment: WRONG.  `destDIR` would be unset.  The particular line would attempt to execute `/data` with `destDIR` as the environment.

Comment: @devnull: Yes, I actually just realized. But in that case, there would be only one argument to `mv` and the files should have been left untouched, so there's clearly something else to it.

Comment: Note: Updated answer again to correspond to the edit to the question.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Thank you for the helpful suggestions - I am very new to bash scripting and I use it to manage many files I generate for my PhD research (i.e. I am not a professional programmer but I am eager to learn proper coding). I did not run as root, or to be exact, I executed as ./move_data.sh. Also, per the argument-list-too-long comment, I read your post wrong the first time, I used *.mat for the one-liner not the syntax you suggested, so I'm not sure if I would have gotten the argument list too long error.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Both of these directories are located on external hard drives. I checked the upper-most directories on both and the files are not there - is there somewhere else they might be?

Comment: @mr.cooper: I meant the system's root directory, not the root directory of those external drives.

Comment: @Dolda2000: right, I checked there as well. No luck. I'm working in OS-X btw.

Comment: Hmm. I can't really see what else might have happened, given the appearance of the script. You may want to create a dummy file in your source directory and run the script on only that files, adding the `-i` and `-v` flags to `mv`. `-v` will let you see what exactly `mv` does with it.

Comment: tried and I get permission denied error: ./dumb.sh: line 4: /data: No such file or directory
mv: rename /Volumes/Travroth/calibration4/three/data/dummy1.mat to /dummy1.mat: Permission denied
mv: rename /Volumes/Travroth/calibration4/three/data/dummy2.mat to /dummy2.mat: Permission denied. But it looks like you are correct and it is trying to move it to the root directory

Comment: That is indeed what I would have expected to have happened on the first run as well. Something else must have changed since the first time you ran the script. Does it look exactly the same? Did you have any environment variables set (like, say, an outside setting of `destDIR`), or some other process state changed?

Comment: Oh no I think you figured it out. Yes, you are correct in a previous line of the code I set destDIR and then this line was supposed to update it. Basically I have two destDIR's and instead of creating unique variable names for each I expected the original destDIR to be overwritten. I imagine this means I wrote over the files in the other directory.